# How do you import a layered macro across files within a crate in Rust?

Tags: rust, module, macros

I have macro calls another macro. This is a simplified version of the file (the actual outer macro has matching logic).

```
macro_rules! outer_macro {
    () => (
        inner_macro!()
    )
}

macro_rules! inner_macro{
    () => (
        // stuff
    )
}
```

Everything worked when I had these macros in the same file where `outer_macro` was called (`src/caller.rs`), but I moved them to their own file `src/macros.rs` and now `src/caller.rs` can't find `outer_macro`.

I tried adding `#[macro_export]` above `outer_macro` and `pub mod macros;` to `src/lib.rs`. Now `src/caller.rs` can find `outer_macro`, but `outer_macro` can't find `inner_macro`.

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! outer_macro {
    () => (
        inner_macro!()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
}

macro_rules! inner_macro{
    () => (
        // stuff
    )
}
```

How do I make `outer_macro` usable to the rest of my crate while keeping `inner_macro` in its scope?

Comment: The traditional solution is to merge the macros into a single macro and use [internal rules](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/internal-rules.html) for the inner macro.

Comment: @Jmb Actually, some consider this an old way from before macros could use proper namespacing.

Comment: Is `outer_macro!` crate-internal or public?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman according to [the little book of Rust macros](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/minutiae/import-export.html): "_Unfortunately, this only applies for external crates_ […] _scoping applies there_ [in edition 2018] _the same way as before_ [in edition 2015] _as well_"

Comment: @Jmb I don't know if this is since edition 2018 or later, [but you can have proper namespacing on macros today](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96de855369c7cc0f61d3cea70da6415e).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman apparently tlborm is right, scoping only works fully between crates, not between modules of the same crate: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a2f6684c8d3b1774d18c85c5748c97e)

Comment: @Jmb Sure, items are still resolved at expansion site. Hopefully this will be fixed for macros 2.0.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `outer_macro!` is crate-internal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the macro doesn't actually reference `inner_macro`; it instead simply copy-pastes the string `inner_macro!()` into wherever the macro is getting used. Therefore, the `inner_macro` has to be a valid path everywhere; with other words, use an absolute path inside of `outer_macro`:

*src/macros.rs*:

```rust
macro_rules! outer_macro {
    () => {
        crate::macros::inner_macro!()
    };
}

macro_rules! inner_macro {
    () => {
        // stuff
    };
}

pub(crate) use inner_macro;
pub(crate) use outer_macro;
```

*src/main.rs*:

```rust
mod macros;

fn main() {
    macros::outer_macro!();
}
```

> "How do I make `outer_macro` usable to the rest of my crate while keeping `inner_macro` in its scope?"

You can't, that's the point of macros: they acutally replace the macro invocation with new code, that means that the new code that is getting inserted has to be valid for the invocation location as well. Meaning, if you use an `inner_macro` call inside of `outer_macro`, both have to be visible at wherever `outer_macro` is being used.

---

An alternative would be to use [internal rules](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/internal-rules.html), as @Jmb pointed out:

```rust
macro_rules! outer_macro {
    () => {
        crate::macros::outer_macro!(@inner_macro)
    };
    (@inner_macro) => {
        // stuff
    }
}

pub(crate) use outer_macro;
```

This would in fact hide the inner macro.

Comment: Ah hah! That makes so much more sense! I just replaced the `inner_macro!()` calls with `crate::inner_macro!()` in `outer_macro` and it works! 

Thanks so much for the help!